# How to get the value from the drop down box django?

Tags: django, drop-down-menu

Should I use the next construction?

```
def PageObjects(request): 
    q = bla_bla_bla(bla_bla) 
    answer = request.POST['value'] 


<form action="PageObjects" method="get">
       <select >
        <option selected="selected" disabled>Objects on page:</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="40">40</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
       </select>
       <input type="submit" value="Select">
  </form>
```

How can I solve this problem? What do I need to write?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would recommend sending your data with post:

```
<form action="PageObjects" method="post">
  <select >
    <option selected="selected" disabled>Objects on page:</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
```

And you should access your form values through the `cleaned_data` dictionary:

```
def page_objects(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = YourForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
      answer = form.cleaned_data['value']
```

I really recommend that you read the Django docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view

Comment: i answered to user Paritosh Singh about my problem. how can i fix it if i will use your recommendation?

Comment: @MaxL You really should follow good http practices when deciding whether to use `POST` or `GET`. Here's a good article on how to decide which method fits your scenario http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get. But I definitely don't think there's enough info here to say one over the other.

Comment: @AustinA thanks for advice, but I asked this question 2 years ago :)
Now I have more experience :)

Comment: What if you have multiple dropdowns in a form, we can declare id for each select tag, how can we access the value of a particular dropdown in the view using 'id' attribute?

Answer (score 23):

give a name to  tag, like

```
<select name="dropdown">
    <option selected="selected" disabled>Objects on page:</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
    <option value="50">50</option>
</select>
```

Access it in view like

```
def PageObjects(request): 
    q = bla_bla_bla(bla_bla) 
    answer = request.GET['dropdown']
```

Comment: and can i use the GET method? explain me how it will send the value from the dropbox to my view.py?

Comment: it depends on the form method you are using, if you are using <form method="get"> you can use GET else use POST. In case you want it to access any (whether GET or POST) use REQUEST.

Comment: In your case, you should use GET, see changes in answer

Comment: what problem your are facing. means are you getting ?dropdown=<something> in url...

Comment: it's doing the action "PageObjects" and changing my URL to .../list/PageObject and show the 404 error because that URL is not written into my urls.py

Comment: then how ur form will get submit, u need to write a view for submitting your form, and what action you are writting in your form the view and url for that view should exist. If you can put here proper code snippet form and view, I can explain you better.

Comment: the view which you wrote in question, from which url is it resolved.

Comment: how i can do it without urls.py?

Comment: i am asking you to write regex for urls on which form is acting upon in urls.py or just write your urls.py code here.

Comment: `from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_detail, object_list
from piston.resource import Resource

from models import DevModel, RackBox, Device
from forms import DevModelForm, RackBoxForm, DeviceForm
from netdev.views import PageView

urlpatterns = patterns('netdev.views',
    #RackBox
    (r'^rackboxes/$', login_required(PageView.as_view())),
    (r'^rackbox/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', login_required(object_detail), { 'queryset': RackBox.objects.all() }))`

Comment: Hi @yakudza_m, in your form you are using action="PageObjects" when you click on submit it forms url as PREVIOUS_URL+'PageObjects' and here you have got no regex for 'PageObjects' so it is not working and givng you 404 error. just give write a regex for that thing, which resolves to view PageObjects.
I think you are directly writing action as name of your view which is not at all correct.

Answer (score 2):

make a file forms.py inside of 'your_app_folder'

in forms.py:

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    FILTER_CHOICES = (
        ('time', 'Time'),
        ('timesince', 'Time Since'),
        ('timeuntil', 'Time Untill'),
    )

    filter_by = forms.ChoiceField(choices = FILTER_CHOICES)
```

in views.py

```
from .forms import FilterForm

def name_of_the_page(request):
 form = FilterForm(request.POST or None)
 answer = ''
 if form.is_valid():
  answer = form.cleaned_data.get('filter_by') 
  // notice `filter_by` matches the name of the variable we designated
  // in forms.py
```

this form will generate the following html:

```
<tr><th><label for="id_filter_by">Filter by:</label></th><td><select id="id_filter_by" name="filter_by" required>
<option value="time" selected="selected">Time</option>
<option value="timesince">Time Since</option>
<option value="timeuntil">Time Untill</option>
</select></td></tr>
```

Notice the option field with attribute selected, when you submit the form, in your views.py file you will grab the data from `selected` attribute with the line

```
answer = form.cleaned_data.get('filter_by')
```