# Send selection from bootstrap dropdown button with Django

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, post, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to send the the selected option from dropdown button (Bootstrap) through a post request with Django. I've been able to find a solution using javascript but I would like to find a solution that cuts out the javascript.

One possible way to do this is seen in [Max L's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586038/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-drop-down-box-django). However, this drops the styling gained from bootstrap and adds another button to send the request. What I would like is to be able to send the request when a user clicks on an option in the dropdown menu.

Another approach is I could place links as the dropdown options and use them to redirect to a different page, but I would really prefer to use a post request.

My attempt at this has mainly followed the bootstrap example code for drop down buttons with the addition of a form tag around the button. How could I get this to work?

```
<div style="float:right">
  {% if forloop.last %}
  <!-- Single button -->
  <div align="right" class="btn-group">
    <form method="POST" action="confirmaction">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Intended Action <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul name="aid" class="dropdown-menu">
        {% for aid, name in actions %}
        <!--from context dict, use keyname = aid to grab value-->
        <li value="{{ aid }}"><a{{ name }}</li>
        {% endfor%}
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Let me know if you need any other information from me and thanks!

Comment: Can't be done without JS.

Comment: :( I guess this just points to the fact that I need to become more comfortable with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to make a POST without JavaScript, is to click on a form button. Check this codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qdPJYw

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <form method="POST">
            <button type="submit" class="btn" name="option1" >
               POST ACTION 1
            </button>
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In addition you need to some css to make button appears the same as dropdown link.