# How to know if which selected in django template select?

Tags: django, select, django-templates

In my django templates how can I know which select option is selected?

```
          <select id="platformid" name="platform">
            {% for x in list %}

              <option value="{{x.company}}">{{x.company}}</option>

            {% endfor %}
          </select>
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/11586830/15978450

Comment: In the request data when the form is submitted, or with Javascript if your purpose is front-end related.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail please?